# MFC prevent dropdownlist to be closed

Tags: winapi, mfc

I create a custom combobox that has a custom listbox. The default listbox of combobox is replaced by using this code:

```
m_comboBoxInfo.cbSize = sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO);
if (::GetComboBoxInfo(m_hWnd, &m_comboBoxInfo)){
    m_ListBox.SubclassWindow(m_comboBoxInfo.hwndList);
}
```

I want the new drop-down list of the combobox is showed always, even if it loses focus or user clicks to other controls.
I tried to capture WM_CAPTURECHANGED and WM_KILLFOCUS at WindProc() function to do nothing.

```
LRESULT CCustomListBox::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_CAPTURECHANGED ||
        message == WM_KILLFOCUS){
        return TRUE;
    }
    return CCustomListbox::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

However, it not work. Could you please show me how to prevent closing dropdown listbox when it loses focus on.

[My combobox looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIqdD.png)

Comment: You could also try to handle `WM_ACTIVATE` or `WM_NCACTIVATE` to do nothing but I believe you will have a hard fight against the system. You may instead use the `CBS_SIMPLE` style which makes the listbox always visible.

Comment: Why use a combo box with forced drop list always showed? That breaks the combo concept. Why not just use a list box?

Comment: @zett42 Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to handle WM_ACTIVATE & WM_NACTIVATE to do nothing but it still not work. The dropdown list closes when I click on other controls.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I want to make a combobox that its dropdown list is closed when the user clicks to the combobox button.

Comment: So have you tried looking into `CComboBox::ShowDropDown`. The MSDN says: "Shows or hides the list box of a combo box that has the CBS_DROPDOWN or CBS_DROPDOWNLIST style." See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch.aspx#ccombobox__showdropdown. See also `CComboBox::GetDroppedState`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I do use the CComboBox::ShowDropDown() function to show the dropdown list when the user click to the combobox button, but the dropdown list is closed everytime it loses focus. That's the problem.

Comment: "CBS_SIMPLE
Displays the list box at all times. The current selection in the list box is displayed in the edit control." this style looked like what you want in the Windows 3.11 times  :)   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775791(v=vs.85).aspx#combo_box_types_and_styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the new drop-down list of the combobox is showed always, even if it loses focus or user clicks to other controls.
>
> I want to make a combobox that its dropdown list is closed when the user clicks to the combobox button.

With these requirements, I would get rid of the combobox altogether and instead just combine an **edit control**, a **button** and a **listbox**. You would have full control over everything without having to fight against standard combobox logic. Even if you would get a "hack" working now, it is very likely to break in future Windows versions.

Simply toggle the listbox's show state when the button is pressed. React to selection change event of the listbox to update the text in the edit control.

I would group these controls in a parent control that at least has the `WS_CHILD|WS_TABSTOP` and `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` window styles set. The latter is important to enable keyboard navigation into and out of the child controls as if the parent control doesn't exist. The "group" control will also encapsulate the notifications from the button and list control (as these are implementation details not intended for the parent of the group control).

You could even emulate notification messages of a regular combobox by sending  `WM_COMMAND` messages to the parent of your "group" control.

Comment: Why can't he use a combination of `CComboBox::GetDroppedState` and `CComboBox::ShowDropDown` to show it on demand? Although I am inclind to agree with you!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Showing the LB is not the issue, but preventing it from hiding when the focus is lost. This is something that was not intended by the combobox design (except from `CBS_SIMPLE`, but this propably require hacks too).

Comment: @zett42 My custom combobox is combined by a custom button and a custom listbox. However, I don't know how to show the listbox (show it on top of the button when there is not enough of space at bellow. etc) , so I subclass the dropdown list of the combobox. It seems that this way is harder to do.

Comment: Just have the edit and button. Put the list box in its own dialogue and set it up as a popup etc. Create it on demand and position it. You  but I think it needs to be modeless since you seem you want user to still interact with dialogue. It just doesn’t make sense to have an overlapping popup listbox. Sounds more like a modeless popup to me.

Comment: @ThànhLongNguyễn I think we could use a screenshot or mockup of how your UI should look like. My suggestion was similar to the `CBS_SIMPLE` style, but now it sounds you actually want a popup listbox. But then I would not understand, why a regular combobox would not suffice. Maybe you could edit your post to clarify a bit.

Comment: @zett42 at first time, I tried to make my custom listbox to be "popup-able" by using this code: m_listbox.Create(WS_POPUP,.....);
Of course, it doesnt work.
Hence, I try to replace the default listbox of the combobox by using "SubClassWindow", and the default listbox automatically closes its dropdown list.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle thank you. It works now.
2 days ago, I got the window class of the deafult dropdown list, it named "ComboLBox". I thought it just a customize of listbox control, I mean just another control. And I tried to show the control as a popup window, of course it doens't work. :-)

Comment: @zett42 thank for your support. My painful days is over. Thank you very much.